# Strange characters

Tags: special-characters

How can I convert from (french characters):

```
&#xC0; l&#x27;origine
```

to:

```
À l'origine
```

?

Comment: You need some kind of encoding/decoding, please provide more details.

Comment: Exactly - which software are you using with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be down to a code page or encoding. They look like they could be UTF8, and from an XML/HTML document.

Answer (score 1):

These characters are encoded using HTML escaping. The general form is:

```
&#xNN;
```

where `NN` is the hexadecimal character number of the character to encode. Your characters probably correspond to the following:

> `À` = C0 (in [code page ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1))
>     `'` = 27 (in ASCII)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can work on .NET framework with a console application and can use the sample code down below.

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace HTMLUtilsBaby
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string myDecodedString = WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&#xC0; l&#x27;origine");
        }
    }
}
```

myDecoded string will have the value that you want. 
Thanks